# Ubuntu 20 on VMWare - Network not working

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu virtual machine does not show wireless and cannot connect to the network:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: VMs will never show your host's wireless adapter.  You connect to wifi on the host and then use the **Bridged Adapter** mode to bridge to your wireless card.  That will give your VM internet access.

Comment: Previously it showed wired 1000 Mb/s but now it doesn't show up anymore and I also tried using the Bridged Adapter but it still doesn't work.